# iOS - How can I get the IndexPath of the last item in a tableview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I would like to automatically scroll to the end of a table view.

```
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```

Given that I know how many item are in the tableview using:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

How can I get the IndexPath * to the last item in this tableView? This is needed so that I can provide it as an argument to scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated

Thanks!

Comment: see my answer..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603598/get-last-cell-in-a-uitableview-section/31873722#31873722

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can get the *indexPath* of the last row in last section like this.

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(numberOfRowsInLastSection - 1) inSection:(numberOfSections - 1)];
```

Here, *numberOfSections* is the value you return from `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` method. And, *numberOfRowsInLastSection* is the value you return from `numberOfRowsInSection:` method for the last section in the table view.

This can be placed in a subclass or category to make it easy:

```
-(NSIndexPath*)indexPathForLastRow
{
    return [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self numberOfRowsInSection:self.numberOfSections - 1] - 1 inSection:self.numberOfSections - 1];
}
```

Comment: depending on where you use this make sure to do a bounds check `MAX(0, numberOfRowsInLastSection - 1)`

Comment: Just to complement the answer, a complete method could look like this      `-(NSIndexPath*)lastIndexPath
    {
    NSInteger sectionsAmount = [myTableView numberOfSections];
    NSInteger rowsAmount = [myTableView numberOfRowsInSection:sectionsAmount-1];
 
    
    NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(rowsAmount - 1) inSection:(sectionsAmount - 1)];
    
    return lastIndexPath;
}`

Comment: Note that this will error if the last section has no rows

Comment: How to do this in Swift?

Answer (score 32):

To get a reference to the last row in the last section…

```
// First figure out how many sections there are
NSInteger lastSectionIndex = [tableView numberOfSections] - 1;

// Then grab the number of rows in the last section
NSInteger lastRowIndex = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:lastSectionIndex] - 1;

// Now just construct the index path
NSIndexPath *pathToLastRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRowIndex inSection:lastSectionIndex];
```

Answer (score 14):

In swift 3

```
let lastRowIndex = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: tableView.numberOfSections-1)

if (indexPath.row == lastRowIndex - 1) {
     print("last row selected")
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Here is an extension in **Swift 4.x** that takes into consideration that there may not be any rows, so it avoids out of range crashes.

```
import UIKit

extension UITableView {
    func lastIndexpath() -> IndexPath {
        let section = max(numberOfSections - 1, 0)
        let row = max(numberOfRows(inSection: section) - 1, 0)

        return IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
    }
}
```

Then call it from your viewcontroller with:

```
let lastIndexPath = tableView.lastIndexPath()
```

Comment: First of all it should be

 func lastIndexPath() -> IndexPath {
        let section = max(numberOfSections - 1, 0)
        let row = max(numberOfRows(inSection: section) - 1, 0)

        return IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
    }

Comment: But it doesn't take into consideration that they might not even exist sections

Comment: @PaoloMusolino You can perform the following experiment to confirm that a `UITableView` always has at least one section. `let tableView = UITableView(); print(tableView.numberOfSections) // 1`

Answer (score 9):

try this:

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
if(indexPath.row == myArray.count -1)

{
     myIndexPath = indexpath;
}
```

myIndexPath should be object of `NSIndexPath`

Comment: What does myArray refer to?

Comment: myArray.count is number of rows insection

Comment: Note that this only works if the `numberOfRowsInSection` just simply does `return myArray.count;`.  That probably is the case for the vast majority of cases, but if `numberOfRowsInSection` does anything extra, this answer won't work (one would have to pretty much repeat everything that is there and subtract 1).

Answer (score 9):

Probably someone will need the same for `UICollectionView`, 
so I updated *Ryan Grimm*'s answer for it:

```
NSInteger lastSectionIndex = [self.collectionView numberOfSections] - 1;
NSInteger lastItemIndex = [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:lastSectionIndex] - 1;
NSIndexPath *pathToLastItem = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:lastItemIndex inSection:lastSectionIndex];
```

Answer (score 4):

Most of the answers here, including the accepted answer, do not take into account the valid cases of a table view with zero sections, or a final section with zero rows.

The best way to represent those situations is using an index of `NSNotFound`, which is accepted by UIKit in methods such as `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:`.

> NSNotFound is a valid row index for scrolling to a section with zero rows.

I use the following method:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)bottomIndexPathOfTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSInteger finalSection = NSNotFound;
    NSInteger finalRow = NSNotFound;

    NSInteger numberOfSections = [tableView numberOfSections];
    if (numberOfSections)
    {
        finalSection = numberOfSections - 1;
        NSInteger numberOfRows = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:finalSection];
        if (numberOfRows)
        {
            finalRow = numberOfRows - 1;
        }
    }
    return numberOfSections ? [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:finalRow inSection:finalSection] : nil;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like all the solutions don't consider that the **last section may have no rows at all**. So here is a function which returns the last row in a last non-empty section:

**Swift 3:**

```
extension UITableViewDataSource {
    func lastIndexPath(_ tableView: UITableView) -> IndexPath? {
        guard let sections = self.numberOfSections?(in: tableView) else { return nil }
        for section in stride(from: sections-1, through: 0, by: -1) {
            let rows = self.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: section)
            if rows > 0 {
                return IndexPath(row: rows - 1, section: section)
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //...

    func scrollToLastRow() {
        if let indexPath = lastIndexPath(tableView) {
            tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    //required data source methods
}
```

Comment: Hey bro, can you give us a Usage example?

Comment: stride(from: sections-1, **through**: 0, by: -1)

Comment: @wye Exactly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 answer, with out of bounds checks. Implemented as a tableview extension

```
extension UITableView {

    var lastIndexPath: IndexPath? {

        let lastSectionIndex = numberOfSections - 1
        guard lastSectionIndex >= 0 else { return nil }

        let lastIndexInLastSection = numberOfRows(inSection: lastSectionIndex) - 1
        guard lastIndexInLastSection >= 0 else { return nil }

        return IndexPath(row: lastIndexInLastSection, section: lastSectionIndex)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
//   get number of section
let indexOfLastSection = self.yourTableView.numberOfSections - 1

// Then get the number of rows in the last section

if indexOfLastSection >= 0{
    let indexOfLastRow = self.yourTableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexOfLastSection) - 1
    if indexOfLastRow >= 0{
        let pathToLastRow = IndexPath.init(row: indexOfLastRow, section: indexOfLastSection)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Swift 5 implementation ensures a valid `IndexPath`.

```
extension UITableView {
    
    /// Returns nil if the table view has no rows.
    func kjy_indexPathOfLastRow() -> IndexPath? {
        let sectionsCount = numberOfSections
        guard sectionsCount > 0 else {
            return nil
        }
        for section in (0..<sectionsCount).reversed() {
            let rowsCount = numberOfRows(inSection: section)
            if rowsCount > 0 {
                return IndexPath(row: rowsCount - 1, section: section)
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```