# Get last cell in a UITableview section

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsindexpath

I have a section in UITableView which has multiple rows. I wish to get the last row or the last cell of the section to add a disclosure indicator on it.

One way I am thinking to use is:

```
NSIndexPath *lastCellIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:[self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:2]-1 inSection:2];
```

Is there any other best way to get the cell or indexpath of the last cell on a section?

Comment: You can get it from your datasource from which you set in delegate methods.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
    NSInteger totalRow = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section];//first get total rows in that section by current indexPath.
    if(indexPath.row == totalRow -1){
         //this is the last row in section.
    }
```

hope it helps.

I did this in **tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:** method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Answer (score 13):

Swift version:

```
let totalRows = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section)
//first get total rows in that section by current indexPath.
if indexPath.row == totalRows - 1 {
    //this is the last row in section.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        //Section 0
        if (indexPath.section == 0) {

            // Is Last row?
            if ([dataSouceArray count] == (indexPath.row+1)) {
                //Yes

                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;


            }
            else{
                // other rows

                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

            }


        }


    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't make a typo in this line: `[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:`??

Comment: There you go :) But is it in willDisplayCell and not in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Answer (score 1):

You should do this inside your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. You can easily detect that which section this cell belongs to and whether it's the last one.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder how i did miss it. The easiest solution is here..
I wrote in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method according to my requirement.

```
if (indexPath.row ==userAccountsList.count-1)
{
    NSLog(@"last row it is ");
       }
```

In the above code userAccountsList is array which we are passing to tableview.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4 version:-**

```
  let totalRow =
            tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section)
        if(indexPath.row == totalRow - 1)
        {
            return
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from your datasource from which you set in delegate methods,
the datasource you assign in
 `numberOfRowsInSection` method.

**[arrayStores lastObject];**

so in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method you can easily check it,